# jQuery selector fails with double quotes in string

Tags: jquery, selector, double-quotes

I'm using the following selector with a string containing double quotes:

```
var something = 'This string contains "double" quotes';

$('*[my-data-attribute="' + something + '"]').click(function () {

});
```

This gives:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Which could be the best solution to solve it ?

Comment: Have you tried using backticks(``) for the selector instead of the single quote?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [quotes in Jquery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817338/quotes-in-jquery-selectors)  Use: `$('*[my-data-attribute="' + something.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"]')`

Comment: use \ slash, the best or easy way to manage single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use one single quote and second double-quotes. You need to use the same quote like

```
var something = 'This string contains "double" quotes';

$('*[my-data-attribute="" + something + ""]').click(function () {

});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  You can create a snippet (edit and click `[<>]`, copy in your code and add jquery from the options on the left) to demonstrate your code working.  In this case your code gives a similar error: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: *[my-data-attribute="" + something + ""]`  Using `""` doesn't "escape" the quote in javascript (it may in other languages (VB?))